# Page content leaking into footer

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I just can't shake this page moving into the footer.

Site is: https://raiderwriter.engl.ttu.edu/super/onecolumn.asp

The #wrapper div is supposed to push a 70px margin down onto the footer, I think? I just want the footer to float below.

Argh.

Answer (score 5):

Your `#wrapper` DIV has

```
margin-bottom: -70px
```

Remove that declaration.

Btw, debugging CSS is pretty straight forward. Just select the problematical element in the browser's dev tools and inspect its applied CSS styles. Then you can disable individual styles to see what changes that produces on the page.

[image]

Comment: +1 You got there before me ;). Could set it to `70px` (remove the minus).

Comment: I must be doing the sticky footer wrong then. I thought the one div had to be -footerheight and the footer had to have footerheight.

Comment: @Caveatrob Hm, sticky footer? Shouldn't the footer then be absolutely positioned?

Comment: not with the method i was using in the past. hmmm